# f:debug not working in backend + TYPO3 8

Tags: typo3-8.x

I want to debug in my custom extension backend module but `f:debug` not working in backend.

Also I have set `'debug' => true,` for both backend and frontend in `Localconfiguration.php` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check your `Application context`. if it is `Development` then `<f:debug>` works.

Answer (score 0):

```
<f:debug>foo</f:debug>
```

Should still work. Have a look at the bottom of your BE output.

Comment: Works also in LIVE mode